# Telegram API MarkdownV2 Escape Characters Bug

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, markdown, telegram

I am new to this. I am writing a telegram bot that interacts with Google Sheets in Google App Script. I am having an issue with MarkdownV2.

My code has one \ before the '!' as Telegram said in their document:

> '!' must be escaped with the preceding character \

```
var send = url + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + id + "&text=" + "Hey\! New item" + "&parse_mode=MarkdownV2";
```

However, it says I  need to use two \\ instead.

```
Exception: Request failed for https://api.telegram.org returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: can't parse entities: Character '!' is reserved and must be escaped with the preceding '\\'"} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
```

But when I use two \\ I still have a problem running.

```
Exception: Invalid argument: https://api.telegram.org/botxyz:abc/sendMessage?chat_id=xyz&text=Hey\!%20New%20item&parse_mode=MarkdownV2
```

When I run the link [https://api.telegram.org/botxyz:abc/sendMessage?chat_id=xyz&text=Hey\!%20New%20item&parse_mode=MarkdownV2](https://api.telegram.org/botxyz:abc/sendMessage?chat_id=xyz&text=Hey%5C!%20New%20item&parse_mode=MarkdownV2) in the error, it connects to Telegram normally.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
var url = "https://api.telegram.org/botxyz:abc";
var id = "xyz";
var send = encodeURI(url + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + id + "&text=" + "Hey\\! New item" + "&parse_mode=MarkdownV2");
console.log(send)
```

- I thought that in your situation `\!` might be `\\!`.
- When this script is run, `https://api.telegram.org/botxyz:abc/sendMessage?chat_id=xyz&text=Hey%5C!%20New%20item&parse_mode=MarkdownV2` can be seen in the log. This value is the same as the URL you tested at the bottom of your question.

#### Reference:

- [encodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

Comment: Thanks so much! By grouping the entire ```send``` by ```encodeURI```, it works now.

Comment: @Rex Nguyen Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

try to moderate your string with:

> yourString
> .replace(/([[^][]*](http[^()]*))|[[]()~>#+=|{}.!-]/gi,
> (x,y) => y ? y : '\' + x);

In all other places characters '_', '*', '[', ']', '(', ')', '~', '`', '>', '#', '+', '-', '=', '|', '{', '}', '.', '!' must be escaped with the preceding character ''.